# perimeter of ellipse

Tags: conic-sections, elliptic-integrals, arc-length

As it is well-known, there is no formula for expression of perimeter of the ellipse $(\frac{x}{a})^2+(\frac{y}{b})^2=1$, as an elementary function of $a$ and $b$. I am interested to find an exact formulation of this fact, and its proof.

Especially, could one impose conditions on  $a$ and $b$,  such that an elementary function expression of perimeter is available? (Loosely speaking, similar to Galois theory which discusses about  solvability of  polynomial equations). Is there a purely algebraic formulation of the problem?

Comment: You should probably read a bit about elliptic integrals.

Comment: I want a prove that shows that an elliptic integral is not  in general expressible by means of elementary functions. Are there any algebraic proofs for example? @IttayWeiss

Comment: [Chebyshev's theorem on elementary integrals](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Chebyshev_theorem_on_the_integration_of_binomial_differentials) states that $\int x^p(a+bx^r)^q\, dx$ has an elementary integral iff one of $(p+1)/r$, $q$, or $(p+1)/r + q.$ Now as far as I can see, the Legendre form of the elliptic integral of the second kind (which is the one that gives the perimeter of an ellipse) isn't quite of this form. It is $\int \frac{\sqrt{1-k^2x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx.$ But I think it is close enough that the same techniques work